# bootstrap modal html content knockout binding not applying popover

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When I use the popover control in my modal the bindings do not work. 
Here is the default content :

```
<form id="a" class="form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: SaveModal">
                                                            <div class="modal-body modal-content-form">
                                                                Default Content
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-modal-submit" value="Submit">
                                                            </div>
                                                            </form>
```

When I click my button 
     `<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" data-title="Information"  btn-block'=""><i class="fa fa-print"></i>Quote Proposal</button>`I get the new Content:

```
 <form id="a" class="form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: SaveModal">
                                                        <div class="modal-body modal-content-form">
                    <div class="panel-group">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                          <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse001391ce-ebdb-4423-b525-40f97835fa53">Modal Controls</a>
                          </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse001391ce-ebdb-4423-b525-40f97835fa53" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                          <div class="panel-body"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Coverage Special</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                                                <input id="CoverageSpecial" name="CoverageSpecial" data-bind="value: CoverageSpecial" type="number" step="any" class="form-control control-font">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <a tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="left" title="TextBox Numeric Help : FAQs" data-content="  
  This control is an html textbox of type (TextNumeric). The values
  that are allowed are between a (Minimum) and a (Maximum)
  integer. The (Precision) allowed will dictate the amount of
  numbers after the decimal. It is (Required) and will
  render a label with the (Name) value. 
"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>
                                                    </span>
                             </div>
                             <span class="help-block"></span>
                     </div>                                
                </div></div></div>
                          <div class="panel-footer"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div></div>

                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-modal-submit" value="Submit">
                                                        </div>
                                                        </form>
```

The problem is that knockout does not work if I dynamically append content. Why?

Comment: That is how Knockout works, it will only bind to DOM which has already been rendered. so when you dynamically load content they are not bound, you may keep the modal content in your HTML hidden , may be by some if condition.

Comment: Try re applying bindings.

Comment: Crummy! Please advise how to load a modal with content. I cannot simply load all my modals on load.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout doesn't listen to changes made to the DOM. It processes the DOM tree once (after you call `applyBindings`) and creates event listeners and subscriptions to make sure stuff gets updated once needed. Some bindings, like the `with` binding, can re-apply bindings to *parts* of the DOM when needed.

Here's an example of a very basic way to force knockout to re-apply bindings:

- We swap out parts of the DOM by using an `html` binding and an observable that holds the partial HTML
- After each swap, we re-apply bindings to the *inner part* of the element that has the `html` binding: you **cannot** apply bindings to an element twice; the outer element is already bound to our initial vm

This example serves to show how knockout works, and isn't the best solution. Managing multiple binding contexts by hand can get messy. I'd suggest creating a custom binding that does this for you. Also, this solution only supports partial views that have *one* parent element.

```js
var content1 = "<h1 data-bind='text: label1'>test</h1>";
var content2 = "<h2 data-bind='text: label2'>test</h2>";

var partialContent = ko.observable(null);

var reapplyBindingsToPartial = function() {
  var partialVM = {
    label1: "Heading 1",
    label2: "Heading 2"
  };

  var partialElement = document.querySelector(".js-partialView").firstChild;

  ko.applyBindings(partialVM, partialElement);
};

var swap = function() {
  if (partialContent() === content1) {
    partialContent(content2)
  } else {
    partialContent(content1);
  }

  // By now, the `html` binding was re-evaluated
  reapplyBindingsToPartial();

};

var vm = {
  partialContent: partialContent,
  swap: swap
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
swap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="js-partialView" data-bind="html: partialContent"></div>

<button data-bind="click: swap">
  swap
</button>
```